# why does my local hosts file enable me to see remote server php files?

Tags: php, http, hosts-file

I have a hosting package with some company. They give me a temporary URL at which I can access the site and see HTML files. But when I try to access PHP files it gave me an error (500 Internal Server Error). I contacted the hosting company and they said I had to change my **local** hosts file by putting the temporary IP and the (non-temporary) hostname in a new line, e.g.:

```
 68.48.122.170 finalwebsite.org
```

(I have changed the names of the site and IP address)

I didn't believe it, but I changed it and then suddenly the PHP file displays correctly. Can anyone explain me why changing this local hosts file allowed me to avoid an internal server error remotely? I thought the hosts file is only used to resolve hostnames.

Comment: The host probably setup an additional virtual host configuration that had the PHP engine disabled.  By adding a host entry you were instructing your system to use the alternate virtual host config.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the hosts entry you made, and then perform an NSLookup on the domain name does it resolve to the same IP they instructed you to put in the HOSTS file?

I'm guessing it won't, and if that's correct then it's most likely because they've only configured a specific server instance to deliver your PHP (especially since you keep using terms like "test" and "temporary") and attempting to access it with the usual public host name and IP address may direct you to the wrong server (due to load balancing, or because the test server is not part of their usual server farm that answers that domain name/IP, etc.)

Comment: Hi Technie007, thanks so much for taking the time to reply in detail!

Comment: I followed your suggestion and I performed a NSlookup. Just to make things clearer, here is a list of the different addresses that are in the game:

Comment: * FINAL_URL (finalwebsite.org in my original question) - this URL currently does not point to the new temporary hosting, but instead it points to where my site was previously hosted.
     * TEMPORARY_URL - this is the URL where I can currently access the hosting, read HTML files, but without changes to the hosts file PHP files cause an internal error.
     * TEMPORARY_IP (68.48.122.170 in my original question) - this is the IP address that the temporary URL resolves to.

Comment: So just to clarify, the hosting company asked me to put the following line in my hosts file:
 TEMPORARY_IP FINAL_URL

Comment: So I followed your suggestion and I removed that entry from my hosts file. Then I did the nslookup:
 nslookup FINAL_URL
Result: a completely different IP address which is what the FINAL_URL currently points to.

Comment: If I do nslookup TEMPORARY_URL
Result: TEMPORARY_IP

Comment: Is that what you expected? I notice also that even though I removed the item from my host file, I now *can* open the TEMPORARY_URL correctly, even showing PHP files without the internal server error. Is there some cache that I need to clear? This would surprise me because the nslookup of FINAL_URL does *not* resolve to TEMPORARY_IP anymore (when I've removed the line from the hosts file).

Comment: Sorry if this is confusing - greatly appreciate any help with this.